# Does the transclude function in the ngRepeat directive's linking function not include data and events in its clone?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have tried to wrap a plug-in that we are using in a directive. This has worked well. Then we tried to use the directive wrapper in a ngRepeat. Suddenly the plug-in stopped working. After stepping through the plug-ins code it appears that the problem is that the plug-in relies on sticking data into element and retrieving it later.

After I logged the results of

```
$(element).data();
```

for both elements appearing in the repeater and outside the repeater the difference was that the element inside the repeater had no data and then one outside still had its data. I see that the transclude function passes in a clone. I read in the JQuery docs that by default data and events are not copied. But I couldn't manage to find if angular.js is using its own clone method or the JQuery one and whether or not it is in fact cloning data and events.

Answer (score 0):

Could this have to do with ng-repeat elements having their own scope? Look at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: No it has nothing to do with ngRepeat having their own scope, I am aware of that. Like I said, the issue is that data (JQuery.data()) and events are not copied in the clone. I am looking for confirmation